# How to remove an arbitrary node while traversing a singly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a singly linked list with x number of nodes, where some of the nodes are duplicates. I need to remove the duplicates while traversing the list, so I end up with a new list that only contains unique nodes. However, I also need to calculate the average of all the duplicates, such that the unique list will contain these average values.

Example 1: 
Say I have a list like this:
a[1] -> b[2] -> c[3] -> a[2] -> a[3] -> b[2] -> null

After traversing the list, I should end up with this list:
a[2] -> b[2] -> c[3] -> null

Example 2: 
Say I have a list like this:
a[2] -> a[2] -> a[5] -> b[2] -> b[4] -> c[3] -> null

After traversing the list, I should end up with this list:
a[3] -> b[3] -> c[3] -> null

I think I need a way to delete the duplicate nodes as I'm traversing the list but I cannot figure out how. Can someone guide me how to go about accomplishing this? Some pseudo-codes would be great. Thanks.

Edit: Solved my problem. See answer for details...

Comment: You say you want to remove duplicates, but the examples you posted do something different.

Comment: Like Jakub said, i didn't understand why a[1] is a duplicate a[2] if they have a different key. I missing something?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't going to do your homework for you.  There are a gazillion questions for reference about deleting a node from a linked list.  Traversing a list to find an average is also relatively simple.  There are dozens of ways to solve this, but your assignment probably also has constraints you haven't listed like how many unique symbols there are, and if you're allowed to copy it to an intermediate data structure.  Write some code and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: this is not homework, otherwise I would have tagged it as such. I did not ask for any codes, just some ideas/pseudo-codes how to solve my problem.

Comment: Jakub & lucholes: Sorry if my question is not clear. The node has two fields i.e. a[1]: id = a, value = 1. so I wanted to find all nodes with the same ids and average their values. Finally, I should end up with a list that contains only unique id nodes and their average values.

Comment: If it's not homework, you are seriously using the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve my problem. Just to share if someone else faces the same problem in future.

To recap, the problem is as follows: I have a singly linked list that contains x number of nodes (x is arbitrary). Each node has two fields i.e. id and value. Within this list, some of the nodes are duplicates i.e. they have the same id. The number of duplicates for each id is also arbitrary. I need to remove all the duplicates and at the same time average their values. Finally, I should end up with a list that only contains unique id nodes (and their respective averages). Number of unique node is also arbitrary (not known beforehand).

Example 1: Before: a[1] -> b[2] -> c[3] -> a[2] -> a[3] -> b[2] -> null. After: a[2] -> b[2] -> c[3] -> null

Example 2: Before: a[2] -> a[2] -> b[6] -> b[2] -> b[4] -> null. After: a[2] -> b[4] -> null

Pseudo codes:

1. Save the first id and value into variable i.e. id=head->id, val=head->val;
2. While list if not empty i.e. head != null;
3. Assign head to current pointer and head->next to next pointer i.e. currPtr=head; nextPtr=head->next;
4. While we traverse the list using next pointer and it is not empty i.e. nextPtr != null;
5. Compare node pointed by nextPtr with id.

   If they are the same, add the node's value to val i.e. val += nextPtr->val. Set the current next pointer to point to next next pointer i.e. currPtr->next = nextPtr->next. Free nextPtr. Then set next pointer to point to current next pointer i.e. nextPtr = currPtr->next.

   Else, set current pointer to next pointer and next pointer to next next pointer i.e. currPtr=nextPtr; nextPtr=nextPtr->next;
6. Once the list if fully traversed by next pointer, average val (can add to new list if needed).
7. Delete the first node, so now head points to next node in the old list.
8. Repeat step 2-7.

Codes:

```
struct node {
    char id[32];
    int val;
    struct node *nextNode;
}; 

void deleteNode(struct node **startPtr) {
    struct node *currentPtr = *startPtr;

    *startPtr = currentPtr->nextNode;
    free(currentPtr);
}

.... //other functions

int main () {
    ...
    char id[32];
    int val, cnt;
    struct node *head = NULL, *currPtr, *nextPtr;

    .... //ask user to input the list 

    while (head!=NULL) {
        strcpy(id,head->id);
        val = head->val;
        cnt = 1;
        nextPtr = head->nextNode;
        currPtr = head;
        while (nextPtr != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(nextPtr->id,id)==0) {
                val += next->val;   
                cnt++;
                currPtr->nextNode = nextPtr->nextNode;
                free(nextPtr);
                nextPtr = currPtr->nextNode;
            } else {
                currPtr = nextPtr;
                nextPtr = nextPtr->nextNode;
            }
        }
        deleteNode(&head);
        printf("Node: %s, Value: %d\n",id,val/cnt); //or save into another list
    }

    .... //do other things
}
```